# Yammer export API example files

Tags: yammer

The [documentation](https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/data-export-api) is a great first port of call for an introduction to the Yammer export API.  It gives a great example of what the API gives back detailing the file types, etc. I would like to see some sample files. Does anybody know where I may find these? Even better, in a perfect world, is there some kind of simulator to demonstrate the use of the API?

I don't have admin access therefore can not see the exports from my network.  I will probably never get this type of access. We wish to see examples so we can decide if its worthwhile requesting an export on a schedule from the global people who do have admin access.  Making this request is time consuming and not all that straightforward.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a forum for programming questions only. Anything else is off-topic. I edited your original question to sound like something that is appropriate and can be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your administrator will not grant you access to the data export for your Yammer network, you do have an option to test the data export and see what it looks like in practice:

- Sign up for a [trial O365 subscription](https://products.office.com/en-us/business/office-365-enterprise-e3-business-software) for a tenant that includes Yammer.
- Post some test content.
- Perform a data export.

If you need the tenant to live longer than the trial period, you'll need to pay for it. Depending on who your are working for, you may be able to assign some licences for a test tenant. Maintaining a separate test tenant is a best practice.

Comment: Thank you for the info, very helpful